# Regex search, visual block results and then sort

Tags: sorting, vim

Let's say I have a list of URLs separated by a white space with their corresponding titles.

```
http://url1.com/qfwarsas/ gb_title 1 - 1
http://url2.com/arsas/ xe_title 2 - 2
http://url3.com/qfsas ah_title 3 - 3
```

I'm trying to sort the lines by the titles to look like this:

```
http://url3.com/qfsas ah_title 3 - 3
http://url1.com/qfwarsas/ gb_title 1 - 1
http://url2.com/arsas/ xe_title 2 - 2
```

I can do it by running a simple macro to copy out the first letter of each title to the front of the line, then ctrl+v sort the blocks, then remove the first letters of each line. I wonder if there's a way to do it using regex and visual block selection?

Regex to get title first letters selection is

```
:s/\v[^ ]* (.)/\1/
```

but when i try to convert that into visual block selection i'm running into issues.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which issues are you running into?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your separator is a white space, you can use

```
:sort / /
```

The default behavior of `:sort` using a search pattern is to sort on whatever *follows* the match.

Comment: Wow thanks! I though I had to run sort on a visual selection but i guess direct sort on search results work too.